# Why do PyMongo scripts take a minimum of 500ms to execute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

This trivial script `test.py` always takes more than 500ms to execute:

```
import pymongo
pymongo.MongoClient(host='127.0.0.1')
```

Like so:

```
lanroth@ubuntu:~$ time python3 ./test.py 
real    0m0.608s
user    0m0.096s
sys     0m0.012s
```

I've tried this on different Linux machines running Ubunutu 16.04, Mint 19, Mongo in a Docker container, or bare metal. The script always takes over 500ms and usually between 580ms and 650ms.

The delay seems to occur when the script exits, so my guess is during cleaning up of connections something is timing out after 500ms.

Executing the following shell command `time echo 'show dbs' | mongo` takes around 8ms, so I'm fairly sure it's something to do with PyMongo, not MongoDB.

Comment: I think you are on to something. Maybe you should try closing the mongoclient when done.

Sorry I do not use python that much, but something in the lines of:

import pymongo
mc = pymongo.MongoClient(host='127.0.0.1')
mc.close()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I already tried that to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoClient` initializes a `PeriodicExecutor` in the `__init__`:

```
executor = periodic_executor.PeriodicExecutor(
    interval=common.KILL_CURSOR_FREQUENCY,
    min_interval=0.5,
    target=target,
    name="pymongo_kill_cursors_thread")
```

As you can see, `min_interval` is 0.5 seconds. According to `PeriodicExecutor._run` method, the thread will sleep for at least 0.5 seconds:

```
def _run(self):
    while not self.__should_stop():
        try:
            if not self._target():
                self._stopped = True
                break
        except:
            with self._lock:
                self._stopped = True
                self._thread_will_exit = True

            raise

        deadline = _time() + self._interval

        while not self._stopped and _time() < deadline:
            time.sleep(self._min_interval)
            if self._event:
                break  # Early wake.

        self._event = False
```

Changing 0.5 to 0.1 directly in the code reduces time from 0.6 to 0.2 on my machine:

```
(main-4hIy5yvR) ➜  main time python ./main.py
python ./main.py  0.07s user 0.02s system 15% cpu 0.596 total
(main-4hIy5yvR) ➜  main time python ./main.py
python ./main.py  0.08s user 0.02s system 49% cpu 0.203 total
```

Comment: That worked for me too and answers my question - thank :-) Now I just need to figure out how to kill this executor from my script...

Comment: You can extend `MongoClient` class and override `__init__` to either replace `PeriodicExecutor` with more efficient or just remove it at all. They explained why `PeriodicExecutor` uses sleep calls: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/doc/developer/periodic_executor.rst . In short - there are issues in Py2. If you are targeting Py3, replacing sleeps with events might be a good start. Otherwise just remove executor.

Comment: this periodic executor is taking up about half of my runtime. What did you mean exactly when saying `remove it at all`. When I set it to `None` it throws exceptions, so not sure how to get rid of it. @awesoon

Comment: `What did you mean exactly when saying` - I meant write your own executor which does nothing. Note that executor actually performs some cleanup tasks, so I encourage you to inspect the actual implementation to see if disabling it suitable for you